# How to store the Json Data

Tags: jquery, json

I have converted the XML data to JSON data now I want to pass this JSON data to the JQuery grid plugin .Please tell me how can I do this.How to store the JSON Data and How to pass the Data To the JQuery grid plugin.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you done the conversion server- or client-side?

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a simple javascript object like:

```
var obj = data;
```

and than reference it with `obj.variableName`.